# Memory Ballooning in Linux/Unix on VMware ESXi

Tags: linux, vmware-esxi, unix, memory

I need help to reclaim the ballooned memory in a Linux/Unix machine. Please help me out. I found some solutions but they are not feasible for me on the production server.

I just need to know how can I reclaim the ballooned memory without rebooting or moving the machine to another host.

Answer (score 3):

Ballooning only happens under some very specific conditions. For VMware ESXi to "inflate" the balloon driver in a VM, the host must be under very heavy memory contention, commonly less than 4% of free memory on the host.

The idea with the balloon driver is for VMTools to start consuming memory inside the VM, to which the OS of the VM responds to by giving the balloon driver memory pages. The balloon driver doesn't actually need these pages for anything, but it tells the hypervisor which memory pages the VM doesn't actually use for anything, so they can be safely discarded by the hypervisor. If this doesn't solve the memory contention problem on the host, the hypervisor continues to inflate the balloon driver, up to 65% percent of the assigned virtual memory by default, which causes the OS on the VM to start swapping to disk. This is not a great outcome, but it's a lot better than the hypervisor swapping to disk instead as the OS on the VM actually knows what pages makes sense to swap to disk.

The way to limit ballooning is to either turn it off per VM (not a great strategy), or to reserve memory for a VM. If a VM has say 4 GB of RAM and a 3 GB memory reservation, the balloon driver can only inflate to 1 GB.

As ballooning is a bit of a last ditch strategy for ESXi, it almost always means that you have too little memory installed on your host.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I think the best option is the reserve Memory for VM.

Comment: But again my concern was related to reclaiming the ballooned memory without rebooting the machine. Please help me out if there is any solution....

Comment: @AbdullahManzoor Adding a reservation should make ESXi back off.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `sched.mem.maxmemctl` parameter for the VM to specify the maximum amount of memory (in megabytes) that can be reclaimed from the guest via memory ballooning. This can also be set to 0 to disable ballooning entirely for the guest.

Note that if ballooning is taking place, your host most likely needs more physical memory to be installed. Ballooning lets ESXi take "unused" memory from guests and use it for other guests, but modern OSes really don't have "unused" memory anymore, as anything they do have gets used for e.g. storage caching. So the guest performance can be reduced when this memory is taken away.

Comment: i have already tried with sched.mem.maxmemctl parameter with 0 value but this impacts the machine performance. Due to this I face slowness issues on the machine. In the actual case, I am not worried that why the machine is using balloon memory but is there any way around to reclaim that memory... when the Physical host memory utilization is normal.

Comment: What is the total guest memory configured, and the physical memory of the host? Overcommitting memory is probably not a good idea.

Comment: The total Guest Memory is 8 GB and the physical host memory is 128 GB...